# Salesforce Opportunity Object and Custom Object

Tags: reporting, custom-object

I'm using Opportunity Object and I've created a custom object: `Postal_Code__c`.

Originally, there was not relationship between the 2 object. I wanted to start reporting on these 2 objects, so I created a lookup from the `Opportunity` Object`to the`Postal_Code__c` object.

I went also created a Custom Report Type yet i'm not able to pull data from `Postal_Code__c` object to the `Opportunity` Object, even though in the Custom Report Type report i can see all of the Custom object's fields.

Comment: did you define in the CRT that you included as primary object Postal Code with or without Opportunities?

Comment: CRT is on opportunity and include The custom object, if understand your question correctly.

Comment: When you say CRT report, I assume you mean the CRT `Edit layout` page?  Do your Opportunities selected in the actual report filters that exploit the CRT actually have values in `Opportunity.postal_code__c`. Does the running user have CRUD access to `Postal_Code__c` and FLS to `Opportunity.Postal_Code__c`

Comment: Did you populate the lookup on existing Opportunity records? You won't get any PostalCode__c results until Opportunity records  have relationships to PostalCode__c records.

Comment: Let's forget about the CRT report for now. Opportunity had no relationship to the custom object. Both objects (Opportunity and the custom Object) have data in them now. there is a custom field on both objects that holds 5 digits zip code. The question is can i match the custom object record with the Opportunity record based on the custom zip code field that both objects have?